# Non-Xeon Motherboards work with Xeon chips?

Tags: xeon

Purchased a XEON (LGA1366 XEON) chip and need a Motherboard for it. Can I run a regular LGA1366 motherboard without XEON specs? Will I be hampered in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel will tell you "no", but I've heard reports that it's possible to do this in some cases anyway.  I wouldn't expect it to just work, though.